# How to convert an existing List/Collection to IAsyncEnumerable

Tags: c#, .net, async-await

I have an interface which specifies an `IAsyncEnumerable<T>` return value, but for a specific implementation I have the results cached in memory as a `List<T>`.

Is there a more straightforward way to return this list which already exists as an `IAsyncEnumerable<T>` without having to actually iterate over it? It seems list I shouldn't need the additional overhead of creating an iterator function.

```cs
public async IAsyncEnumerable<PartitionModel> GetAllPartitionsAsync([EnumeratorCancellation] CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
{
    // _cache.GetOrAddAsync() returns List<PartitionModel>
    var list = await _cache.GetOrAddAsync(CacheKey, () => FetchAllPartitionsAsync(cancellationToken), CacheOptions);

    foreach (var item in list)
        yield return item;
}
```

Comment: A `List<>` doesn't implement `IAsyncEnumerable` so you can't just cast it. Even if you could, what would be the behavior? Block until everything is returned? Yield after every item? Yield after N items? That's not a decision that can be made by the runtime.

Comment: An extension method [`ToAsyncEnumerable`](https://github.com/dotnet/reactive/blob/main/Ix.NET/Source/System.Linq.Async/System/Linq/Operators/ToAsyncEnumerable.cs) for `IEnumerable<T>`s is available in the [System.Linq.Async](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Async) package (owned by the [dotnetfoundation](https://www.nuget.org/profiles/dotnetfoundation)).

Comment: That still enumerates the list

Comment: @TheodorZoulias thanks, I had avoided using that package due to the namespace conflicts with EF Core until version 6 is released but I'll give it another look! https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/24041